# How to make return to previous Activity with on back pressed?

Tags: android, back-button

I have an activity called `MainAct` and `SubAct`. `MainAct` is the parent of `SubAct`.

In `SubAct`, I am playing a music background. In order to stop the music when I press back button, I implement this code below :

```
@Override 
    public void onBackPressed(){
      if (tick != null){
          if(tick.isPlaying())
              tick.stop();

          tick.release();
      }
 }
```

With that code, the music is stopped as I expected. but the problem is I cannot go back from `subAct` to `MainAct`...

I know this is trivial, but can you show me the correct way to do this?

Comment: Show me your Intent code? remove `finish();` when your Intent

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just put back your `super.onBackPressed()` call

```
@Override 
public void onBackPressed() {
      if (tick != null){
          if(tick.isPlaying())
              tick.stop();

          tick.release();
      }

     super.onBackPressed();
 }
```

`super.onBackPressed()` because if we look in [Activity.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/app/Activity.java#Activity.onBackPressed%28%29) (Android 2.2)

```
public void onBackPressed() {
        finish();
}
```

Comment: can u explain why put  super.onBackPressed();  ??
it worked but i need an explanation

Answer (score 4):

Just call the following method inside the `onBackPressed()` method and this will close your activity...

```
finish();
```

as follows...

```
@Override 
public void onBackPressed(){
    if (tick != null){
        if(tick.isPlaying())
            tick.stop();

        tick.release();
        finish();
    }
}
```

You can also do this by calling `super.onBackPressed()` inside your `onBackPressed()`...so that it will maintain the default behavior of `onBackPressed()` method...

```
@Override 
public void onBackPressed(){

    super.onBackPressed()

    if (tick != null){
        if(tick.isPlaying())
            tick.stop();

        tick.release();
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: @studentknight if this has solved your problem then please accept it as answer

Answer (score 3):

Call the finish() method to end the current activity.

Answer (score 2):

Call `finish()` This is will pop the current activity from back stack and the previous Activity in the back stack takes focus.

Also look at the activity lifecycle and stop your music in `onStop()` or `onDestroy()`.

Clicking back button will call `finish()`. No need to override `onBackPressed()`. Just handle the life cycle methods methods properly.

Answer (score 2):

just use

```
@Override 
public void onBackPressed() {
      if (tick != null){
          if(tick.isPlaying())
              tick.stop();

          tick.release();
      }

     super.onBackPressed();
 }
```

You need  `super.onBackPressed();` because when you called super class onBackPressed what it is doing is, it is calling  `finish();`

or diectly you can write

```
@Override 
public void onBackPressed(){
    if (tick != null){
        if(tick.isPlaying())
            tick.stop();

        tick.release();
        finish();
    }
}
```